# How to change font size of number dialog android

Tags: android, dialog

My title for my number dialog I made, which is just a normal dialog is too long, and I was wondering how I'd make the font size of it smaller. As I didn't have the option to user a text view.

```
public void numberPickerDialog() {

    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("How many times would you like to decrypt?");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.numberpicker1);
    Button btn1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btn2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final NumberPicker numPicker = (NumberPicker) d
            .findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    numPicker.setMaxValue(100); // max value 100
    numPicker.setMinValue(1); // min value 0
    numPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    numPicker
            .setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal,
                        int newVal) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numOfDecrypt = numPicker.getValue(); // set the value to
                                                    // textview
            Log.w("MyApp", "" + numOfDecrypt);
            d.dismiss();
            messageDialog();
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d.dismiss(); // dismiss the dialog
        }
    });
    d.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to change the size

```
((TextView)alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setTextSize(12);
```

Comment: I don't seem to have COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, any Ideas of what I might have to do/ change it to?

Comment: Use .setTextSize(12);